# remove table id according to php if condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table with the id `example`

```
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <td>Emil</td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
    <td>Linus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove id if nothing was posted.

```
if (isset($_POST['save']))
 {
        ...
    
 }
 else
 {
        echo "
        <script>
        const box = document.getElementById('example');

        console.log(box.getAttribute('id'));

        box.removeAttribute('id'); 
        </script>";
 }
```

It doesn't seem to work. What should i do?

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I don't know, this is just what I tried and couldn't find the reason why it is not working. @NicoHaase

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? How are you testing this, and what are you seeing? Does the `console.log` line show what you expect? Do any errors appear in the browser console?

Comment: No errors, table still shows the features of `example` @IMSoP

Comment: Is the markup generated as you would expect it? Check this through your browser's developer console

Comment: Do you assume the table becomes invisible by calling `removeAttribute('id')`? Can you just not render the table instead of removing it afterwards in JavaScript?

Comment: thanks for the tip, it still has the id example @NicoHaase

Comment: no I don't want to delete the table , just the id. @PeterKrebs

Comment: Why would you need to remove the `id`? It's a bit unclear how that would achieve anything useful in your page. Intrigued as to the rationale for this task

Comment: P.S. By itself, the JS does seem to operate correctly on the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/fedoL06k/ . This assumes of course that the same table is rendered onto the page at that time that JS is echoed, so that the JS can work on it

Comment: I want to use server side pagination as default and client side pagination for other pages (after submitting forms) and the table id triggers jquery datatable all the time. @ADyson

Comment: You look confused.  PHP is running on the server and is used to produce the page.  So, just dont emit that part of the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $id="example";  
    }else{
        $id="";
    }
```

```
<table id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <tr>
    ..
  </tr>
  <tr>
   ..
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please check it may work for you.

Comment: Anytime, good luck & keep coding  :)